# How to split string to multi line string in Bash

Tags: bash

How to split this string in bash script:

```
exclude="'!/module1,!/module2,!/module3'"
echo -pl $exclude
```

I'd like to get something like this, for more readability:

```
exclude="'
        !/module1,
        !/module2,
        !/module3
'"
echo -pl $exclude
```

But in echo comand I get next result:

```
 !module3,
```

I need to get in my echo command next result:

```
-pl '!/module1,!/module2,!/module3'
```

Comment: As there are a plethora of different diverging answers here, it seems your question is unclear. Could you clarify a bit what the real intention is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use:

```
exclude='
        !/module1,
        !/module2,
        !/module3
'
echo -pl $exclude
```

Output:

```
-pl !/module1, !/module2, !/module3
```

I recommend switching from `echo` to `printf`.

Comment: Did you get this output? I tried this, but still get the same result ` !module3,`

Comment: Your string may contain carriage returns from DOS/Windows. Check this: `echo "-pl $exclude" | cat -A`

Comment: Ohh.. you're right. I do this file in WIndows and then execute it in linux bash. I'll try to fix this.

Comment: But, how i can edit it in windows but run in Linux?

Comment: This might help: `echo -pl ${exclude//$'\r'/}`

Comment: Or convert your complete script: `dos2unix your_script.sh`

Answer (score 0):

you can use backslash.
you can write like this.
`exclude="'\ !/module1,\ !/module2,\ !/module3\ '"`
let me know if this help.

Comment: `exclude="'
        \!/module1,
        \!/module2,
        \!/module3
'"
echo -pl $exclude`. I got again `'!module3,`

Answer (score 0):

You can always translate your separator into a newline character, something like this:

```
UNIX prompt>echo "a,b,c" | tr "," "\n"
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation here is to make use of an array and use the asterisk operator for the expansion:

```
exclude_list=(                                          \
                "!/module1"                             \
                "!/module2"                             \
                "!/module3"                             \
)
IFS=","
arg_list=( -pl "${exclude_list[*]}" )
unset IFS
echo "${arg_list[@]}"
```

Comment: `oldIFS="$IFS" ; IFS=, ; ... ; IFS="$oldIFS"` ?

Answer (score 0):

It is encouraged to use `printf`

You can try the following:

```
unset exclude
exclude='
        !/module1,
        !/module2,
        !/module3
'
printf -- "-pl '" ; printf "%s" ${exclude} ; printf "'\n"
```

As already suggested, the bash indexed arrays could be used

```
unset exclude
exclude=('!/module1,')
exclude+=('!/module2,')
exclude+=('!/module3')
printf -- "-pl '" ; printf "%s" "${exclude[@]}" ; printf "'\n"
```

Or if you do not mind an extra   (space) after the `,`:

```
printf -- "-pl '%s'\n" "${exclude[*]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite exclude on an additional line to remove formatting:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

exclude="'
        !/module1,
        !/module2,
        !/module3
'"
exclude=`echo "$exclude" | tr -d ' \t\15\12'`

echo -pl "$exclude"
```

You can use spaces, tabs, unix newlines and windows carriage returns in the first exclude. The `echo` pipe to `tr` removes them.

- `\t` is for a tab.
- `\15` is for carriage return (sometimes referred to as `\r`).
- `\12` is for line feed (sometimes referred to as `\n`).